# Ultimo Less files dont compile

Tags: magento-2.1, less, ultimo

I am using the Ultimo theme.  As per its documents it says to make a child theme and then add any custom css in the provided less file.

I have done this but it is difficult to get it to generate the LESS.  If I update the LESS file and then deploy static content the css file is not updated.

The only way I have found to get it to generate the file is if I switch into developer mode and then switch back to production mode.

In developer mode the site wont even load, it just hangs halfway finished but switching back makes the LESS compile.

I have all caches disabled.  Why doesn't the LESS compile with deploy static content?  Is there a different command to compile the LESS?

Comment: I had same problem, but I have solved temporarily by the help of this article:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

And small tweak for watcher only for current theme:
Made changes on Gruntfile.js , default task:
`
default: function () {
            var tasks = [
                'less:infortis',
                'watch'
            ];
            grunt.task.run(tasks);
        },
`